# OOP Javascript, Why this object doesn't work like expected?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

### What do I want to achieve?

I have an class called Looper. I want to give each object a name and an own looper.

### Results I expect

```
Created Looper Object...
one
Created Looper Object...
two
one - 1
two - 1
one - 2
two - 2
one - 3
two - 3
one - 4
two - 4
one - 5
two - 5
.......
```

### My code

With this code I expect it to work..

```
var Looper = (function (window, document, $) {

    this.i = 1;

    var Looper = function () {
        console.log('Created Looper Object...');
    }

    var getName = function () {
        return this.name;
    }

    var setName = function (newName) {
        this.name = newName;
    }

    var loop = function () {
        console.log(getName() + ' - ' + this.i);
        this.i = this.i + 1;
    }

    var startLoop = function () {
        window.setInterval(loop, 1000);
    }

    Looper.prototype = {
        getName: getName,
        setName: setName,
        start: startLoop
    }

    return Looper;
})(window, document, jQuery);

var one = new Looper();
one.setName('one');
console.log(one.getName());
one.start();

var two = new Looper();
two.setName('two');
console.log(two.getName());
two.start();
```

### [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dvepq/)

### My results

But it doesn't....

```
Created Looper Object...
one
Created Looper Object...
two
result - 1
result - 2
result - 3
result - 4
result - 5
.......
```

Can someone tell me why it doesn't?

My problem is that is can set `this.name` for each object.

But I cannot set `this.i` for each object. They overtake each others `i`. Looks like `this.i` is static?!?!?

Also when I use `console.log(two.getName());` it works. But within the loop `this.name` is `result`?

Comment: It's printing the word "result" in place of `one` or `two`?

Comment: They both loop under the name `result` and they increment each others `i`...

Comment: Oh, result is the name of the frame it is running within in jsfiddle.  Your code is running in the global context and returning `window.name`.

Comment: `this` refers to the `window` object, and it happens that `window.name` in jsfiddle is `result`.

Comment: Why it doesn't refer to Looper?!? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the `this.i = 1;` property inside of the constructor function:

```
var Looper = function () {
    this.i = 1;
    console.log('Created Looper Object...');
}
```

In your current code the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) refers to the global object (`window`), so that you are actually creating a global variable (which is some kind of "static", yes).

A similar thing happens in the function called from [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval), `this` is again set to the global object (that's the reason why it finds the number at all). You need to explicitly [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) your `loop` method on the `Looper` instance, for example by

```
var startLoop = function () {
    var that = this;
    window.setInterval(function() {
       loop.call(that); // "that" refers to the Looper object, while "this" does not
       // if "loop" were a method on the Looper, it's equivalent to
       // that.loop()
    }, 1000);
}
```

or via [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
var startLoop = function () {
    window.setInterval(loop.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

Also, inside the `loop` function you will need to call `getName` as a method on the current Looper object:

```
this.getName()
```

It seems to add a little confusion that all your functions/methods are not only accessible on (inherited) properties of the objects, but also as local variables in your module. Notice that [JavaScript has no classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418980/1048572), and `this` does not work like in Java - you always need to explicitly distinguish between variables and properties. Your module should look more like this:

```
var Looper = (function() {

    function Looper() {
        this.i = 1;
        this.name = null;
        console.log('Created Looper Object:', this);
    }

    Looper.prototype.getName = function() {
        return this.name;
    };
    Looper.prototype.setName = function(newName) {
        this.name = newName;
    };
    Looper.prototype.start = function() {
        var that = this;
        window.setInterval(function() {
            console.log(that.getName() + ' - ' + that.i);
            that.i++;
        }, 1000);
    };

    return Looper;
});
```

Comment: Why `loop.call(that)`?  Shouldn't `that.loop()` do it?

Comment: @DaggNabbit: I had that at first, but then I noticed that his objects actually do not have a `.loop` method - it was not added to the prototype.

Comment: Oh, right. Why is that IIFE there anyway... removing that would make things less awkward.

Comment: Nice, I fixed it with your helpfull answer! :)

Comment: @Bondye: Yes. `this` can refer to anything, like the the DOM node when the function is called as an event handler. Or to the global object (like in your case twice) when called from `setInterval/Timeout` or as a normal function. Or to an object, as you expect it in constructor functions and instance methods.